# How to wait for a Glib::Dispatcher's connected function to finish?

Tags: c++, multithreading, asynchronous, glib, gtkmm

I am currently working myself into multi-threading with Gtk, because I want to update the rows in a `Gtk::TreeView` asynchronously, so that the user doesn't have to wait for the function that updates them until he can use the program, it would just do it in the background.

So I am using a `Glib::Thread` that is running my update function that collects data, and I have connected a function to a `Glib::Dispatcher`, that will then update the actual view.

This works fine when I call the `Glib::Dispatcher` from my threaded data collector, after it has finished collecting stuff, but if I call it every time it has finished collecting a row's data, and let the `Glib::Dispatcher`'s connected function just update this single row, it leads to very strange results, which is, I think, because if i call `my_dispatcher()` from the thread, it is running the connected function asynchronously and doesn't wait for it to complete.

Is there any way I can tell the function that runs in a separate thread, that it should wait for the `Glib::Dispatcher`'s connected function to complete (like using join), but without blocking my main thread, so that just the other thread waits for it?

Answer (score 0):

I think I have stumbled upon an answer for this finally now. Im using a `std::condition_variable` to block execution & communicate between the threads. Seems to work well - I hope it stays like this :D